# Redux Thunk async/await fetch is not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

Hi I am trying to call API to create a user but unfortunately, I am able to do so. Can anyone help me here? I am calling an action from the signupScreen.js file and in the action, I am dispatching the function but not sure what's wrong. Here is an example of that.

**singupScreen.js**

```
import * as AuthActions from "../../../../store/actions/user/auth";
...
const submitCredentialHandler = useCallback(()=> {
    let newUser = {
        firstName: signupFormState.inputValues.fName,
        lastName: signupFormState.inputValues.lName,
        email: signupFormState.inputValues.email,
        password: signupFormState.inputValues.password,
        gender: signupFormState.inputValues.gender
    }
    AuthActions.register(newUser);
},[signupFormState]);
```

**actions/auth.js**

```
export const register = userRegisterData => {
    console.log('in action');
    console.log(userRegisterData); // Here it show data
    return async dispatch => { // Doesn't come under dispatch function.
        console.log('in action 2'); // This is't get printed. 
        try {
            console.log('in action 3');
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://xyz./rest/V1/customer/register',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(userRegisterData)
                }
            );
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong');
            }
            
            const resData = await response.json();
    
            console.log(resData);
            await dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER', user: userRegisterData});
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('in action 5');
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
.
.
.

import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import AuthReducers from "./src/store/reducers/user/auth";

const App: () => Node = () => {
  
  const rootReducers = combineReducers({
    auth: AuthReducers,
    // cart: cartReducer
  });

  const store = createStore(rootReducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
  
  return (
    <Provider store = { store }>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {/* <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}> */}
          <StatusBar barStyle={'dark-content'} backgroundColor="white"/>
          <AppNavigationHandler />
        {/* </SafeAreaView> */}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
});

export default App;
```

I am new to this so maybe I am missing or doing anything wrong. Please help to figure out the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
You need to dispatch action like this

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
...
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submitCredentialHandler = useCallback(()=> {
    let newUser = {
      firstName: signupFormState.inputValues.fName,
      lastName: signupFormState.inputValues.lName,
      email: signupFormState.inputValues.email,
      password: signupFormState.inputValues.password,
      gender: signupFormState.inputValues.gender
    }
    dispatch(AuthActions.register(newUser));
  },[signupFormState]);
...
```